# What am I doing wrong? strpos, strlen, and preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match, strpos

So essentially I'm opening a large file (I think it's large - 19MB) and trying to comb out anything that's not a 4 letter .com and dropping from the registry on todays date. So what I am trying to do below is call out the file and for each line in it find strings with date in line and 35 or less in characters (prior to stripping chars).

Then I want it to check that it's a .com has no didgets and does not contain a hyphen.

What am I missing?

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$extension = '.com';
$lines = file('PoolDeletingDomainsList.txt');
//$lines = file('testdomains.txt');
$date = date('n/j/Y');

echo "<b>4 Letter premiums for ". $date .":</b><br />";

foreach($lines as $line)

if ((false !== strpos($line,$date)) && (35 <= strlen($line))) {

  $line = preg_replace('/12:00:00 AM,AUC\b/','<br />', $line);
  $line = preg_replace('/,9\/28\/2013/', '', $line);

  if ((false !== strpos($line, $extension)) && (0 === preg_match('#\d#',$line)) && (0 === preg_match('/-/', $line))){
    echo $line;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: first thing I can notice is that 35 <= strlen means "lines at least 35 chars long", not "35 chars or less"

Comment: I'm an idiot. The drop file doesn't contain today on it :@

Comment: All is working with the above + Paul's fix.

Answer (score 1):

Try `(35 >= strlen($line)` rather than `(35 <= strlen($line)` if you want lines 35 chars *or less*. Personally, I prefer to order comparisons like that the other way around, e.g. `strlen($line) <= 35`, which I think is more readable and avoids mistakes like the one you just made :)

Comment: Yea, I switched them around and originally had it as stated above, I guess it makes no difference, but easy to forget to flip the symbols. .